# knockoutjs: With-binding to a template with a specific Observable Array object in index number

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am trying to pass a specific object in a `ObservableArray` defined in my view model to a template with the index number.

In my view, it looks like this:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: "fooTemplate", with: FooCycles()[0] } --><!-- /ko -->

<script id="fooTemplate" type="text/html">
  //some HTML for a individual FooCycle here
</script>
```

I got the `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return { name:"fooTemplate",with:FooCycles()[0]} }"` error. Under the with binding, it still focus the parent VM that it belongs to in my JS debugger(Chrome).

I can get access to a specific array object in my model definition that is used for several `ko.computed` properties:

```
var fstsum = parseFloat(self.FooCycles()[0].sum());
var sndsum = parseFloat(self.FooCycles()[1].sum());
```

I can use `FooCycles` in `foreach` with no problem:

```
<!-- ko foreach: FooCycles -->
  <div class="item">
    <!-- ko template: { name: "fooTemplate", with: $data } --><!-- /ko -->
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

`FooCycles()[0]` works in javascript, but not working in Knockout.js. Is there a way to get an array object with index in Knockout?

Comment: I think that I solved my problem. I should use data: not with:.

    <!-- ko template: { name: "fooTemplate", data: FooCycles()[0] } --><!-- /ko -->

It was written in the documentation. This worked as I expected. Thanks for reading.

[The "template" binding]

: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) does not have `with` listed under the supported "additional" parameters provided in the documentation.

The reason it works with your `foreach` is due to:

> data — an object to supply as the data for the template to render. **If you omit this parameter, KO will look for a foreach parameter, or will fall back on using your current model object.**

Change the `with` to `data` and in the case of the `foreach` you can just omit it.